# Keeping Chometzdik Lost Item On Pesach For Non-Jew to Pick Up?

Tags: gentiles, passover, chametz-leaven

When a non-Jewish friend from my hometown was visiting me where I now live, I gave him a gift of scotch.  After receiving the gift, he then accidentally left the scotch at my home. I will be returning to my hometown for Pesach, but will get in right before the holiday so there will be no time to return the item to him.

Is it permitted to keep the item in my parents' home until such time during Pesach when my friend can retrieve his property?  And how does it interact with the chometz selling my parents will do?

My guess is that it is not different from having chometz stored that you sold to a non-Jew, and would be unaffected by a chometz sale of theirs, even one that triggers after, because they do not own it, but I'm sure there are nuances I am not considering.

Comment: I read the other day that one can give chametz to a Gentile as a present, even on condition that he returns the present after Pesach. Clearly, you gave the Gentile a gift, so it is his. The question at play, here, is does it need to be removed from your home before Pesach? I'm inclined to think, no. You may need to move it or cover it once you get home. But, it doesn't seem that you have any problem of owning the scotch by the mere fact that it's in your home.